# Hide all spans that are close to cursor on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project where I have several hundred spans next to each other, with a letter of the text in each span. When I hover over one of the spans, I want to hide it, as well as the other spans nearby.

It makes an image like this:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

My goal is to hide all of the spans in a given distance away from the mouse, like this:

[image: image of my goal]

**HTML**

```
<span id="overlay-1">@</span>
<!-- ... -->
<span id="overlay-142">@</span>
<span id="overlay-143">@</span>
```

I'm able to hide 1 of the spans by calling their ids on mouseover and changing the style to `display=none`, but I want to hide **all** that are in close proximity to the mouse. Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: Interesting question, but you should show a real attempt to resolve the task, just hiding a single element is not enough. You could try to build on an approach, where you've mapped all the spans in an array, that way it's easy to get the surrounding spans of the one under the cursor. And drop the ids, they're totally useless, they only are crowding the global window object.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by 'close proximity'. Your image seems to show a couple of horizontal neighbours on each side going but only one vertical neighbour top and bottom going. Is that right? Also, is the system automatically wrapping within a container so the neighbouring text vertically above and below varies depending on viewport size for example?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to solve this through JS. Here is my code:

```js
function paint() {
    let txt = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        txt += "<div>"
        for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            txt += `<span onmouseout="hoverOut()" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseuop id="overlay-${i}-${j}">@</span>`
        }
        txt += "</div>"
    }
    document.getElementById('painting').innerHTML += txt
}


function hover(x) {
    let id = x.id;
    let i = x.id.split('-')[1];
    let j = x.id.split('-')[2];
    
    for (let a = -2; a <= 2; a++) {
        for (let b = -1; b <= 1; b++) {
            const elem = document.getElementById(`overlay-${i-a}-${j-b}`);
            elem ? elem.style.opacity = 0 : null;
        }
    }
    x.style.opacity = '0';
}

function hoverOut() {
    for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('span').length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('span')[i].style.opacity = 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="paint()">
    <div id="painting">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Gab Yup, Ali has just created 10000 (ten thousand!) global variables ... Please don't use this even in your dreams, rather pick one of the other answers, which are doing the task without `id`s.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach without using `id`s would be to use [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the size and position of the hovered element and then use [`Document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) inside a loop to access elements near the hovered one:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main')
for (let i = 0; i < 800; i++) main.innerHTML += '<span>@</span>'
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span')

const areaWidth = 50
const areaHeight = 50
const hidden = []

function getElements(currentSpan, color) {
  const { top, right, bottom, left, width, height } = currentSpan.getBoundingClientRect()

  for (let col = left - areaWidth / 2; col < right + areaWidth / 2; col += width || 14) {
    for (let row = top - areaHeight / 2; row < bottom + areaHeight / 2; row += height || 14) {
      const el = document.elementFromPoint(col, row)
      if (el?.tagName === 'SPAN') {
        el.style.color = color
        hidden.push(el)
      }
    }
  }
}

spans.forEach(span => {
  span.addEventListener('mouseover', () => getElements(span, 'transparent'))
  span.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    hidden.forEach(el => (el.style.color = ''))
    hidden.length = 0
  })
})
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 640px;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CSS solution - overwrite the adjacent characters with a pseudo element on the clicked character.

This snippet uses a monospace font and it's set line height and letter spacing as CSS variables so you can alter them as required.

```js
function clicked(ev) {
  ev.target.classList.add('obscure');
}
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = '@';
  if (i % 10 == 0) {
    container.innerHTML += '<br>';
  }
  container.appendChild(span);
}
container.addEventListener('click', clicked);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: auto;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  --line-height: 20px;
  --letter-spacing: 5px;
  line-height: var(--line-height);
  letter-spacing: var(--letter-spacing);
}

.container span {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.obscure::before {
  content: '';
  width: calc(5ch + (6 * var(--letter-spacing)));
  height: calc(3 * var(--line-height));
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 0.5ch), calc(-50% + (1ch)));
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want the span to vanish, but you don't want its space to also vanish. display:none is the wrong solution. you need visibility:hidden.

hiding the hovered element and elements before and after it is easy. the difficulty is in hiding element that are above or below it.

to do that, you would need to do some math.

assuming the answer doesn't need to be *exact*, you could do it something like this:

1. calculate the centre positions of all spans and keep them in an array (so you don't need to recalculate every time)
2. when a span is mouse-entered, check the array and calculate all spans that are within radius r of that span's centre point - or just above/below/left/right - whatever works.
3. create a new array of spans that should be hidden
4. check all hidden spans - if any of them are *not* in that new array, unhide them (visibility:visible)
5. finally, go through the new array and set visibility:hidden on all spans in that array

Comment: color white on white background would be also do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit diffrent and custumisable aproch:

```js
// Variables
const ROW = 10; // Total number of rows
const COL = 35; // Total number of items in a row (i.e. columns)
const RANGE = 2; // Total number of items to be selected in each direction
const values = []; // To colect ids of items to be selected

// Utility Function
const push = (value) => {
  if (value > 0 && value <= ROW * COL && !values.includes(value)) values.push(value);
};

// Add items in the root div
const root = document.querySelector("#root");

for (let i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
  root.innerHTML += `<div id="row-${i + 1}"></div>`;

  for (let j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
    document.querySelector(`#row-${i + 1}`).innerHTML += `<span id="item-${COL * i + (j + 1)}">@</span>`;
  }
}

// Add class to the items as per the RANGE
root.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
  values.length = 0;

  const id = e.target.id;
  if (!id.includes("item-")) return;

  const current = +id.replace("item-", "");
  push(current);

  for (let i = -RANGE; i < RANGE; i++) {
    push(current + i);

    for (let j = -RANGE; j <= RANGE; j++) {
      push(current + COL * i + j);
      push(current - COL * i + j);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const item = document.querySelector(`#item-${values[i]}`);
    item.classList.add("selected");
  }
});

// Remove class from the items as per the RANGE
root.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const item = document.querySelector(`#item-${values[i]}`);
    item.classList.remove("selected");
  }
});
```

```css
/* Just for styling purposes */
body {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

#root [id*="item-"] {
  padding: 1px;
}

/* Styles for the selected item */
#root [id*="item-"].selected {
  /* color: transparent; */ /*  Use this to get your intended effect */
  color: #ffa600;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```